# How to display the last date on a grouping set on Kibana

Tags: date, kibana

I am working on a dashboard, and I would like to show the last date on a grouping set.
I take the kibana_sample_data_ecommerce as example. Attachedn an example of row part.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7fcF.png)

I would like to group by product_id, take the last date of each group and then the last date of the hole grouping set. You will find on the aggregation images 1 and 2 what I did. I could only group by product_id and take the take the last date of each bucket.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX6p9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h81k.png)